# Show and hide div on check and uncheck of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide and show div on check and uncheck of checkbox. I am getting the parent and finding the div which I want to hide. But code is not running

Jquery is:

```
$('.show-check').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {    
        $(this).parent().find('.div-check').fadeIn('slow');
    } else
        $(this).parent().find('.div-check').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="type-details">
  <span class="form-label">Logo:</span>
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="show-check" checked>
      <span class="lever"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="landing-inputfile div-check">
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="file-input" placeholder="No file" readonly>
        <label class="input-group-btn">
          <span class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-basic2">
             UPLOAD <input type="file" style="display: none;">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ro8pghw5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script instead

```js
$('.show-check').click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).parents('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeIn('slow');
  } else
    $(this).parents('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="type-details">
  <span class="form-label">Logo:</span>
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="show-check" checked>
      <span class="lever"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="landing-inputfile div-check">
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="file-input" placeholder="No file" readonly>
        <label class="input-group-btn">
          <span class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-basic2">
            UPLOAD <input type="file" style="display: none;">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

*Why your code does not work* :

`$(this).parent()` will give you `label` - and `find('.div-check')` won't return anything.

---

Use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** - to get a common parent which has the desired child element,

```
$(this).closest('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeIn('slow');
```

---

Also, I'd suggest you use `change()` event instead of `click()` on checkbox in the below,

```
$('.show-check').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('input').is(':checked')`

In your example: `$(this).is(':checked')`

You have to use parents() to select the correct wrapper to find your element `div-check`

```
var $check = $(this).parents('.type-details').find('.div-check');
$('.show-check').click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $check.fadeIn('slow');
   } else
       $check.fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$(this).closest(".type-details").find('.div-check')` to get the `div-check` div and hide/show it.

```js
$('.show-check').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest(".type-details").find('.div-check').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).closest(".type-details").find('.div-check').fadeOut('slow');
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="type-details">
  <span class="form-label">Logo:</span>
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="show-check" checked>
      <span class="lever"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="landing-inputfile div-check">
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="file-input" placeholder="No file" readonly>
        <label class="input-group-btn">
          <span class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-basic2">
            UPLOAD <input type="file" style="display: none;">
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show-check').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        $(this).closest('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeIn('slow');
    } else
        $(this).closest('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$('.show-check').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked unchecked');
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).parents('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.type-details').find('.div-check').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});

 <input type="checkbox" class="show-check checked" checked>
```